# StackOverflowException was unhandled: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

i am using asp.net mvc 4 and entity framework 5 in a project. i have a  base Entity that all entities derived from it:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{        
    [Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { set; get; }

    public virtual string CreatedBy { set; get; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime ModifiedOn { set; get; }

    public virtual string ModifiedBy { set; get; }
}
```

First the Account Entity is a class for application user:

```
public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] AvatarBinary { get; set; }
    public string AvatarMimeType { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<AccountInRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Role of the User :

```
public class Role : BaseEntity
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<AccountInRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }
}
```

each User can have multiple Role and vice versa:

```
public class AccountInRole : BaseEntity
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

when i want to give roles for an specific user, call **GetRoles** method in Accountrepository. this is implemented in this way:

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
#region Properties 
private CharityContext DataContext { get; set; }

public IQueryable<Account> Accounts
{
    get { return DataContext.Accounts; }
}

#endregion

#region Ctors 

public AccountRepository() : this(new CharityContext())
{
}

public AccountRepository(CharityContext db)
{
    DataContext = db;
}

#endregion

#region Methods

public List<Role> GetRoles(string userName)
{
    var acc = DataContext.Accounts;

    var query = from u in DataContext.Accounts
                from r in DataContext.Roles
                from ur in DataContext.AccountInRoles
                where ur.AccountId == u.Id && ur.RoleId == r.Id && u.UserName == userName
                select r;
    return query.ToList();
}

#endregion

}
```

in this method, an exception has thrown when the compiler want to run above LINQ query. this exception is:

**StackOverflowException was unhandled**

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**

**{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}**

the GetRoles method are call two time :

one time from the Custom Authorize Attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorize  : AuthorizeAttribute
{   
    //private readonly IAccountRepository _accountRepository;
    private string[] roles;

    //public CustomAuthorize(params string[] roles)
    //{
    //    this.roles = roles;
    //}

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        if (Roles == string.Empty)
            return true;

        var lstRoles = Roles.Split(',');
        AccountRepository _accountRepository = new AccountRepository();
        var userRoles = _accountRepository.GetRoles(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        foreach (var role in lstRoles)
        {
            bool isFound = false;
            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                if (userRole.RoleName == role)
                    isFound = true;
            }
            if (!isFound) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }        
}
```

and second time from the Application_AuthenticateRequest method in the Global.asax.cs :

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cookie = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie httpCookie = Request.Cookies[cookie];
    if (httpCookie == null) return;
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(httpCookie.Value);
    if(ticket == null || ticket.Expired) return;
    FormsIdentity identity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);
    var _accountRepository = new AccountRepository();
    var roles = _accountRepository.GetRoles(identity.Name);
    var principal = new CharityAccount(identity.Name, roles.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToArray());
    Context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
}
```

CharityAccount that ou can see it in above method is implemented in this way:

```
public class CharityAccount : IPrincipal 
{
    private string[] roles;
    private IIdentity identity;

    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return identity; }
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(roles, role) >= 0;
    }

    public CharityAccount(String name, String[] roles)
    {
        identity = new GenericIdentity(name, "Custom authentication");
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

According to your idea, what is the problem?
regards

Comment: why negative grade? i dont understand

Comment: I would imagine the downvote is for the large amount of information - you haven't narrowed this down to where the problem is occurring.  Your stackoverlow is probably happening due to excessive recursion - I'd suggest checking your entity foreign keys to ensure you haven't set up a circular reference.

Comment: I check for circular references, there are not any circular references. this codes work fine but when i add a second **separate** database using ef code first for logging purposes this error was happened.

Comment: What do the mappings look like? You may have made a typo making the mapping going round in circles. But before you add anything, try to remove some less relevant parts.

Comment: I recover project from a backup and now works fine, something that i dont know what is this exactly, is added to the project and caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have done few things which can lead you to troubles. The one I can see is the circular reference of Accounts, roles in AccountinRoles and vice versa.

I have simplified your code though it's not the best design(But I believe in keeping things simple and stupid). You can keep your virtual properties if you really mean what the virtual properties are for in entities.

This working and running fine.

```
  public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { set; get; }
}

public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Role : BaseEntity
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public class AccountInRole
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Operation
{
    public List<Role> GetRoles()
    {
        List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        List<Role> lstRole = new List<Role>();
        List<AccountInRole> lstAccountInRoles = new List<AccountInRole>();

        Account ac1 = new Account
            {
                Id = 1,
                UserName = "Jack",
                Password = "somePassword2",
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
            };
        Account ac2 = new Account
        {
            Id = 2,
            UserName = "Sam",
            Password = "somePassword1",
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
        };
        lstAccount.Add(ac1);
        lstAccount.Add(ac2);

        Role r1 = new Role
            {
                Id = 1,
                RoleName = "TestRole1",
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
            };
        Role r2 = new Role
        {
            Id = 2,
            RoleName = "TestRole2",
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
        };
        lstRole.Add(r1);
        lstRole.Add(r2);

        AccountInRole acRole1 = new AccountInRole
            {
                AccountId = ac1.Id,
                RoleId = r1.Id
            };

        AccountInRole acRole2 = new AccountInRole
        {
            AccountId = ac2.Id,
            RoleId = r2.Id
        };
        lstAccountInRoles.Add(acRole1);
        lstAccountInRoles.Add(acRole2);

        string userName = "Sam";

        // Query the data
        var roles = from u in lstAccount
                    where u.UserName == userName
                    from acc in lstAccountInRoles
                    from r in lstRole
                    where acc.AccountId == u.Id
                    && r.Id == acc.RoleId
                    select r;

        return roles.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the relationship between Account and Role entities are many to many. It must not change. I recover the project from the backup and now works fine. But i don't know exactly what caused this error.